# Pointwise limits in Real Analysis 4

Tags: convergence-divergence

In the following two questions I need to find the pointwise limit of the sequence defined for $x\in R$. I have had some success with the first example and believe I have done it correct. But in the second example I am not sure how to find the pointwise limit or if it is uniformly convergent

1) $f_n(x) = \dfrac{nx+x^2}{n^2}$. Then
$$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) =\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left(\dfrac{x}{n} + \dfrac{x^2}{n^2}\right) = x\left(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{n}\right) + x^2\left(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^2}\right)=0+0=0$$

So this converge pointwise to $0$.

However how do I find the pointwise limit of the following sequence and whether or not that it uniformly converges?

2) $f_n(x) = e^{-(x-n)^2}$

Comment: Observe that $$e^{-(x-n)^2}=e^{-(n-x)^2}=\frac1{e^{(n-x)^2}}$$ Hope it helps.

Comment: Note that $f_n(n) = 1$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Try fixing $x_0\in \mathbb R$ and study $\lim_{n\to +\infty} f_n(x_0)$. In the case you are asking:

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty} e^{-(x_0-n)^2} = \lim_{n\to +\infty} \frac{1}{e^{(x_0-n)^2}}=0$$

because as $n\to +\infty$, as $x_0$ is fixed, $(x_0-n)^2$ becomes larger, and so does $e^{(x_0-n)^2}$.

If you do not see it clear, you can choose some particular values of $x_0$.

---

So $f_n$ converges pointwise to $0$. Now, to study uniform convergence, note that the only possible limit is $0$, because uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence. So you will have to prove that
$$\sup_{x\in \mathbb R} |f_n(x)-0|=\sup_{x\in \mathbb R} |f_n(x)|\to 0$$
as $n\to \infty$.

But, in this case, $f_n(n)=1$, so $\sup_{x\in \mathbb R} |f_n(x)|>1$.

In the general case, it is usually a good idea to find $\sup |f_n(x)|$ using derivatives.

Comment: so does thus prove that it is not uniformly convergent for number 2?

Comment: @Bl409 Yes. If $\sup_{x\in \mathbb R} |f_n(x)| >1$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$, it cannot be $\sup_{x\in \mathbb R} |f_n(x)|\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

For 1), uniform convergence would imply that given some $\epsilon > 0$, you can find $n$ large enough so that $|f_n(x)| < \epsilon$ **for all $x$**. Why is this impossible? (Consider large enough $x$.)

For 2), as $n \to \infty$ the exponent tends to $-\infty$ so the pointwise limit is $0$. For uniform convergence, follow the same approach as 1). For $0<\epsilon<1$, why can't you find $n$ large enough so that $|f_n(x)| < \epsilon$ for all $x$? (See copper.hat's hint: note that $|f_n(x)| \le |f_n(n)|=1$ for all $x$ and $n$.)

Comment: could you further elaborate for the uniform convergence for number 2? trying to understand this logic

Comment: what implicatations does $f_n = n $ for all n have?

Comment: @Bl409 Suppose $\epsilon=1/2$ and you want to verify $|f_n(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x$. This is impossible since $|f_n(n)|=1$.

Comment: so then this is not uniformly convergent since $|f_n(n)|=1$?